# I am getting a JSON/Javascript object because I can see it in my console, but how do I get it to serialize and make my data bind to my Ui elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf, knockout.js

I am using knockout. I am sending dynamic data from my MySql server to a wcf service and then getting my knockout function to display the data in divs. I will post the code below so you can see what I'm talking about.

My knockout model:

```
function machineDataModel(item) {
    this.mach_no = ko.observable(item.mach_no),
    this.VAR1 = ko.observable(item.VAR1),
    this.VAR2 = ko.observable(item.VAR2),
    this.VAR3 = ko.observable(item.VAR3),
    this.VAR4 = ko.observable(item.VAR4)
};
```

Knockout ViewModel:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var machineDataViewModel = {

        machineDataItems: ko.observableArray([]),

        loadMachineDataItems: function () {
            alert('Method 1: Start');
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/JsonRestful/Service1.svc/GetMachineData", function (data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
                //machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.removeAll();
                //alert('Everything Removed')
                alert('Method 2: Start');
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    machineDataViewModel.machineDataItems.push(new machineDataModel(item));

                });
            });
        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings(machineDataViewModel);

    machineDataViewModel.loadMachineDataItems();

    //setInterval( loadMachineDataItems, 10000 );
});
```

I know everything works fine till I get to the alert Method 2: Start. The each method doesn't iterate over the array like I want it to. I get an object in my console where I requested it be posted in the log.  `Object { GetMachineDataResult=[20]}`

My View is:

```
<div id="knockout" data-bind="foreach: machineDataItems">
    <p id="machineNum" data-bind="text: mach_no"></p>
    <div id="Completed" data-bind="text: VAR1"></div>
    <div id="Style" data-bind="text: VAR2"></div>
    <div id="PUPC" data-bind="text: VAR3"></div>
    <div id="RPM" data-bind="text: VAR4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your JSON response actually look like? Likely you are iterating over the wrong property. From your log, I'm going to guess you want `$.each(data.GetMachineDataResult,...`

Comment: Second @MattBurland's comment. [The code as posted works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/vm3vm621/)

Comment: Here is what my Json response looks like in the console [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1h4XSKB9nNWQkpaSDVWR0E2T1E/view?usp=sharing) and here is what it looks like from my WCF service [Click Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bPAjxrm_wlb29fRG40N0ZaX2s/view).

Comment: @MattBurland you sir just saved my life. Thanks and good day to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image of your JSON response you posted in a comment, it looks like your JSON object looks something like this:

```
{
    "GetMachineDataResult": [ // bunch of items here ]
}
```

Note that the array isn't the top level object, it's a property called `GetMachineDateResult`. So instead of:

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) { //...
```

You need:

```
$.each(data.GetMachineDateResult, function (index, item) { //...
```

Because `data` is an object and `data.getMachineDateResult` is the array you want.

Comment: I would give you more points if I could...  I don't know how I could have been so stupid